# Alt+Left Arrow turns screen black

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, ubuntu-gnome

I have Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 installed and every time I press Alt+Left Arrow to go up a directory in my file browser or back a page in my web browser my screen turns all black and there is a terminal cell. Once I press it Alt+Left Arrow again I go to the login screen. Why is this happening and how do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

*Update: I added an additional tag because it is known to happen in 18.04 too.*

Comment: this soln may help you to understand why this happened, but simple reboot will fix that. link is https://askubuntu.com/questions/893964/altleft-key-locks-the-screen/1060009#1060009

Answer (score 13):

There is an open issue about this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1508146

A solution that worked for me was to run:

> sudo kbd_mode -s

Comment: Yes this solved it for me.  `kbd_mode` reports `Unicode (UTF-8) mode` then `raw (scancode) mdoe` before/after this command.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a problem very close to this one. Without changing any keyboard settings, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> begun to take me directly to the graphical login screen. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> took me to the full screen terminal login.
After a couple of weeks, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> also stopped working. That was too much, and I started to study the problem. I noticed in the keyboard settings that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> had been changed to <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (not by me). When I changed it back, also the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Arrow behavior went back to normal.

Comment: Strange thing is that my OS seems to have fixed it's self. A few days after I posted this it stopped doing this.